# Unable to install python-imaging dependency on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: xubuntu

I want to install Ajenti free control panel on my Linux VPS Ubuntu 18.04. I am receiving the following error while installing python-imaging dependency on it. Is there anyone who has the correct command to install python-imaging dependency?

Error Message:

```
  root@VPSforvideo:~# wget http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/pillow/python-imaging_4.0.0-4_all.deb
--2019-08-06 08:20:23--  http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/pillow/python-imaging_4.0.0-4_all.deb
Resolving ftp.br.debian.org (ftp.br.debian.org)... 200.236.31.3, 2801:82:80ff:8000::4
Connecting to ftp.br.debian.org (ftp.br.debian.org)|200.236.31.3|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 50458 (49K) [application/x-debian-package]
Saving to: ‘python-imaging_4.0.0-4_all.deb’

python-imaging_4.0. 100%[===================>]  49.28K   155KB/s    in 0.3s    

2019-08-06 08:20:24 (155 KB/s) - ‘python-imaging_4.0.0-4_all.deb’ saved [50458/50458]

root@VPSforvideo:~# sudo dpkg -i python-imaging_4.0.0-4_all.deb 
(Reading database ... 67081 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack python-imaging_4.0.0-4_all.deb ...
Unpacking python-imaging (4.0.0-4) over (3.1.2-0ubuntu1.1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-imaging:
 python-imaging depends on python:any (<< 2.8).
 python-imaging depends on python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~).
 python-imaging depends on python-pil; however:
  Package python-pil is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package python-imaging (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-imaging
root@VPSforvideo:~#
```

Comment: The `python-imaging` package was replaced sometime after 16.04 by the `python-pil` and `python3-pil` packages. Any instructions that refer to the `python-imaging` package seem quite old and therefore doubtful.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried to install python-pil and python3-pil package but I received dependency error. Do you have a command to install python-pil on Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: Are you asking how to use apt?

Comment: No. My friend, I know how to use the apt command. But when I am going to install python-pil and python3-pil on my Ubuntu 18.04, I am receiving a dependency error. 
Error message:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-imaging : Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
                  Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
                  Depends: python-pil but it is not going to be installed

Comment: Looks like you don't have Python2 installed (unsurprising). Look at the Ajenti dependencies and see if it will accept Python3-pil, which you *do* have installed, Note that the error message in your question seem caused by you using dpkg instead of apt, not by any real problem. Dpkg does not resolve dependencies. Apt does.